# How to prevent a state update on a react onClick function (outside useEffect)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, scope, use-effect

When I use `useEffect` I can prevent the state update of an unmounted component by nullifying a variable like this

```js
useEffect(() => {
 const alive = {state: true}
//...
if (!alive.state) return
//...
 return () => (alive.state = false)
}
```

But how to do this when I'm on a function called in a button click (and outside `useEffect`)?

For example, this code doesn't work

```js
export const MyComp = () => {

  const alive = { state: true}
  useEffect(() => {
   return () => (alive.state = false)
  }

  const onClickThat = async () => {
    const response = await letsbehere5seconds()
    if (!alive.state) return
    setSomeState('hey') 
    // warning, because alive.state is true here, 
    // ... not the same variable that the useEffect one
  }
}
```

or this one

```js
export const MyComp = () => {

  const alive = {}
  useEffect(() => {
   alive.state = true
   return () => (alive.state = false)
  }

  const onClickThat = async () => {
    const response = await letsbehere5seconds()
    if (!alive.state) return // alive.state is undefined so it returns
    setSomeState('hey') 
  }
}
```

Comment: What is causing the component to not be mounted while an onClick handler is still processing? Maybe move the logic from the click handler to the component owning it.

Comment: Just a fast click when there's a timeout of 2 seconds showing a modal

Comment: Sorry, I guess my point was more about figuring out why it's happening in the first place to prevent the scenario instead of just treating symptoms and using stopgaps.

Comment: Your point is totally correct, but in a modal scenario, can't really see how I could prevent the warning if a user is clicking fast while having a modal showing a message, apart from using these stopgaps

Comment: I guess you haven't clearly explained the scenario though. Is it something like a modal is displayed, and "lingers" for a moment after being dismissed and an impatient user is a little click happy?

Comment: yes (well the user is me :)

Comment: Dang :) Issues like this, though, are usually more indicative of an UX problem and not necessarily a software issue. Providing feedback to a user that the first click was received and processing, or defensive UI like disabling an interactive element when later interaction can cause problems, etc...

Comment: In this case, the event aborted is the modal disappearing (with a message saying, it's done), the user can safely ignore the modal or just click because he's already read it or he read it the event before. Don't really see a different way to manage it, but I am ready to learn new things :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a component re-renders, it will garbage collect the variables of the current context, unless they are state-full. If you want to persist a value across renders, but don't want to trigger a re-renders when you update it, use the `useRef` hook.
https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useref

```
export const MyComp = () => {

  const alive = useRef(false)
  useEffect(() => {
   alive.current = true
   return () => (alive.current = false)
  }

  const onClickThat = async () => {
    const response = await letsbehere5seconds()
    if (!alive.current) return
    setSomeState('hey') 
  }
}
```

Comment: Had just checked with a `useState`, but obviously when I updated it I caused a rerender, `useRef` doesn't, and your solution works perfectly, thanks!!